# Per domain traffic stats on a VPS?

Tags: linux, vps, traffic

Is there a way to calculate the amount of traffic going through each domain I've hosted on a VPS? I can see the aggregate traffic through my server - but not individual domains. Are there any more details I should provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the Apache web server, you should be able to run log parsers (such as webalizer) which provide you with decent statistics.

Please click here to view more information:
http://www.webalizer.org